# Notes/Book Suggestion For Understanding Simplicial and Singular Homology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, book-recommendation

Now a days I'm reading some basic algebraic topology from Hatcher's book but I'm having hard time in understanding Simplicial and Singular Homology.

> What are some other "good" notes/books for understanding simplicial and singular Homology ( preferably with more examples than Hatcher's book) ?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You should explain what aspect of Hatcher's exposition is giving you trouble.  Without knowing that, there is no way to make an accurate recommendation.

Comment: @guest acually I'm looking for a textbook with more examples than Hatcher's book!In Hatcher's book I don't really see any motivation for proof of some what big theorems also.

Comment: More examples?!  Have you done the exercises until you reached the homology chapter?

Comment: @guest not really,I'm starting Hatcher's Book from chapter2 (Homology Groups) only because I already know about fundamental groups.

Comment: I take the view that it is useful for motivation to get some feeling for the history and background to the subject, especially for homology theory which took a long time to sort out its current standard expositions. One source I was recommended in the 1950's was the Introduction in S. Lefschetz's "Introduction to Topology" (and nothing else in the book).